# Include additional details in Django error log for improved debugging?

Tags: django

Let's say I have a simple django view like so

```py
# views.py

def view1(request):
    val = 5 / 0
    return JsonResponse({"val": val})
```

and I have the following config for logging with debugging intentionally set to `False`

```py
# settings.py

DEBUG = False
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': f'{BASE_DIR}/logs/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

If I were to call the view, I would see the following statement in my logs

```
Internal Server Error: /view1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/code/app1/views.py", line 14, in view1
    val = 5 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I can easily enable monitoring alerts to be notified of such errors like these when they occur. And I can inspect the log to see what line failed with what exception. But I am lacking other vital information in order to fully debug the issue.

How can I include additional details into this log? Details such as the URL that was called, query parameters, the incoming payload, header values, etc.

Comment: You may find some answers in how Rollbar's middleware (or similar) handles getting the stack trace, url, and some variables like user (https://github.com/rollbar/pyrollbar/blob/master/rollbar/contrib/django/middleware.py)